# Making column using <frameset> but not able to hide that line

Tags: html, css

I am using frameset tag and made 2 column in same HTML page. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to remove that line which is dividing both HTML pages column. So how can I remove that line and hide it. 
Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="first_1.html">
  <frame src="second_2.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this **frameborder="0"** rather than '1' and by this you can hide that line.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="first_1.html" frameborder="0">
  <frame src="second_2.html" frameborder="0">
</frameset>

</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset cols="50%,50%" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="first_1.html" >
  <frame src="second_2.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: set as frameborder for frameset instead og giving each frame